# Debugging React/Flask connection with SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I'm following https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-create-a-react--flask-project attempting to connect a simple Flask backend with ReactJS after using `npx create-react-app` and adding a single flask file.

`package.json`

I've set up a proxy at `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` with a new script command of `yarn start-backend`.

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start-backend": "cd app && python3 app.py",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

`nav.js`

I've set up a `Button` using MaterialUI that calls a function to log a JSON response.

```js
class Nav extends React.Component {

    clicked() {
        fetch('/').then(res => {
            console.log(res.json());
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1}}>
                <AppBar position="static">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <SignUpForm onClick={() => this.clicked()} />
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </Box>
        )
    }
}
```

In the top level directory I've created a directory called `app` that has an `app.py` file with the following code.

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return {"msg": "homepage from the backend."}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

When I use `yarn start` and `yarn start-backend` and click the button, I get the error below

```sh
Promise {<pending>}
nav.js:14 undefined
VM1769:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Attempting to debug, but I'm unfortunately not getting anywhere. There's related questions but nothing seems to work. I've tried moving the flask file to the top level directory, to public, using `http://localhost:5000/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so being new to JavaScript/ReactJS it seems like I was missing two things

1. I didn't have a return for the `Promise` which seems odd in that I thought you didn't have to return things

and

2. Changing the path from `/` to `/api/test` seems to work.

I'll have to dig further to understand but for now it resolves my issue.

Here's the code that's changed

```js
    clicked() {
        fetch('/api/test')
            .then(res => {return res.json()} )
            .then(
                data => {
                    console.log(data)
            })
    }
```

and

```py
@app.route("/api/test")
def home():
    return {"msg": "homepage from the backend."}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('/', {
     headers : { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
         }
}).then(res => {
            console.log(res.json());
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
```

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the same error, but thank you for a possible solution

Comment: if it is not working, please use `axios` instead of `fetch`.